# continuity of the complex square root function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to show that there is no continuous square root function in the complex plane, i.e. a function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with $f(w)^2=w$ for all $w \in \mathbb{C}$.

I already calculated the complex roots $$ z = \pm \left( \sqrt{\frac{|w|+a}{2}} + i \text{sgn}(b)\sqrt{\frac{|w|-a}{2}}\right) $$
of $w$ and want to use this.

If there wasn't a sign ambiguity, the discontinuity of $f(w)=z$ would follow immediately by the discontinuity of the signum. I am not sure how to treat the sign ambiguity, though.

Of course, I could also try polar coordinates but I want to build upon what I have.

Comment: It might be easier to consider $w=e^{i \theta}$ and show that the hypotheses imply that $f(e^{i \theta}) = K e^{i { \theta \over 2}}$, where $K \in \{\pm 1\}$. Then consider $\theta \to \pm \pi$.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the usual way. I just feel like I'm "almost there" with my approach because obviously, the signum-function isn't continuous.